# "autoReconnect" must end with the ';' delimiter

Tags: java, xml, java-ee, servlet

Есть вот такая проблема :

```
 <context-param>
<param-name>URL</param-name>
<param-value>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Test? 
serverTimezone=Europe/Kiev&autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false</param-value>
</context-param>
```

param-value возвращает вот такую ошибку :

```
The reference to entity "autoReconnect" must end with the ';' delimiter.
```

Самое понятно,что я нашел -

> The question mark '?' is not a special character under XML, however the ampersand is. However, you just need to represent it as '&', and everything works okay.

Попробовал вот такой вариант

> jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/baza1250?autoReconnect=true&characterEncoding=cp1250(нашел в комментах)

Не работает...Ошибка та самая.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В XML символ амперсанда надо экранировать. Либо так

```
<param-value>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Test?serverTimezone=Europe/Kiev&amp;autoReconnect=true&amp;useSSL=false</param-value>
```

либо так

```
<param-value><![CDATA[jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Test?serverTimezone=Europe/Kiev&autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false]]></param-value>
```

Comment: Первый вариант не работает.А вот за второй - спасибо!